# Why isn't my python pygame code working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm watching a tutorial on youtube by thenewboston http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9YWzFcHMz78&feature=share&list=EC8E21BDD0981FDF66 and I'm copying his code yet mine isn't working. Whenever I press the down arrow key, the whole program freezes and won't let me quit. I'm using python 3.3. Please help. Here's my code.

```
grey="grey.jpg"
circle="circle.png"

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import*

pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1278,990),0,32)

background=pygame.image.load(grey).convert()
pic=pygame.image.load(circle).convert()

x,y=0,0
movex,movey=0,0

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_LEFT:
                movex=-1
            elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                movex=+1
            elif event.key==K_UP:
                movey=-1
            elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                movey=+1
        if event.type==KEYUP:
            if event.key==K_LEFT:
                movex=0
            elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                movex=0
            elif event.key==K_UP:
                movey=0
            elif event.key==K_Down:
                movey=0
    x+=movex
    y+=movey

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    screen.blit(pic,(x,y))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Line 37 in your code, it should be `K_DOWN` not `K_down`.

Answer (score 4):

Quick run of the code:

```
$ python test1.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 37, in <module>
    elif event.key==K_Down:
NameError: name 'K_Down' is not defined
```

The error is displayed when the program crashes on a down arrow push.

The crash is due to a typo, you have "K_Down" when it needs to be "K_DOWN".

Corrected code:

```
grey="grey.jpg"
circle="circle.png"

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import*

pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1278,990),0,32)

background=pygame.image.load(grey).convert()
pic=pygame.image.load(circle).convert()

x,y=0,0
movex,movey=0,0

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_LEFT:
                movex=-1
            elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                movex=+1
            elif event.key==K_UP:
                movey=-1
            elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                movey=+1
        if event.type==KEYUP:
            if event.key==K_LEFT:
                movex=0
            elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                movex=0
            elif event.key==K_UP:
                movey=0
            elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                movey=0
    x+=movex
    y+=movey

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    screen.blit(pic,(x,y))

    pygame.display.update()
```